# exception handling in executor service

Tags: java, multithreading, future, executorservice

When I throw exception from student name archana.
As per my understanding **InvokeAll** waits for all task to be completed and then return future list

Output I get is

```
 pool-1-thread-1 Helloprerna   
 pool-1-thread-2 Helloabc   
 HELLO SOMEERROR   
 Execution Completed
```

I want other tasks output to be show for which exception is not thrown.Any suggestions

```
public class Executor {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException{

        ExecutorService  executor=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
        list.add(new Student("prerna"));
        list.add(new Student("abc"));
        list.add(new Student("archana"));
        list.add(new Student("def"));
        list.add(new Student("xyz"));
        list.add(new Student("ritu"));
        list.add(new Student("babita"));

        try {
            List<Future<String>> resultList=executor.invokeAll(list);
            for(Future<String> f:resultList){
                //if(f.isDone()){
                    System.out.println(f.get());
                //}
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("HELLO SOME ERROR");
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }

        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          System.out.println("Execution Completed");

    }
}
```

.

```
public class Student implements Callable<String>{
    String name;
    public Student(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(name=="archana"){
            throw new Exception();
        }
        return display(name);
    }

    private String display(String name2) {
        try {
        //  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            name2=Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Hello"+ name;
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return name2;
    }

}
```

Comment: Easiest would be to catch any exception in `call()`. You just need to figure out what to return to indicate that execution did not gracefully finish. Other option would be to enclose the `get()` call inside the for loop with its own try/catch block. Depends on where and how you want to handle exceptional behavior.

Comment: in case of application if we catch a exception in call method what will we return in case of error.I mean how will such error handling be done

Comment: That's up to you. Depends on your design. You could return simply null or an emtpy string or some defined "Poison" constant ... plenty of possibilities. But in your case, I guess it would be more feasable to go about as described in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move around the try/catch:

Original:

```
try {
    List<Future<String>> resultList=executor.invokeAll(list);
    for(Future<String> f:resultList){
    //  if(f.isDone()){

                System.out.println(f.get());

        //}
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (ExecutionException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    System.out.println("HELLO SOME ERROR");
//  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

will be rather:

```
try {
    List<Future<String>> resultList=executor.invokeAll(list);
    for(Future<String> f:resultList){
        try{
            System.out.println(f.get());
        }catch (ExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println("HELLO SOME ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So here you will get all OK results and you can handle the exceptional execution for each task.

Comment: Where should it ideally cach exception inside call method or catching around get

Comment: @coder25 That depends where you could handle the exception in a proper way, so that your application remains in a sound state.

Comment: Well, there isn't really an answer to that specific question because the example code seems rather academic. In a real-life scenario, it would depend on where the exception **can** be handled. If the caller does not need to know about exceptional behavior, do it inside. If the caller needs to take some measures to remain in a consistant state then you must catch outside.

Comment: any real life example to catch inside or outside .I am preparing for interview .

Comment: @coder25 If it is required that all threads exit successfully to get a valid result (like a calculation), you catch the exception outside of the `for` loop. If you, e.g. want to resubmit a task that failed (e.g a webservice call) you catch the exception within the loop, if you just want to log the failure and simply move on (some *fire and forget* scenario) you could do it within the `call()` method (or in the `for`)...

Answer (score 0):

The pattern for this should be: Main thread create and call slaves threads, which should return ok value or error value (if there was any error). Then Main thread should collect results from slaves and process them.

Comment: How do you know? That's totally a design decision.